Query answer column derived from a combination from columns in another table
TNM Staging
I am doing my first project. I have some data t_stage is from t0 to t4, n_stage n0 to n3 and m_stage is m0 and m1.
Different combos of these give different results. So t1,n2,m0 is Stage3a, t4,n1,m1 would be stage 4.
What I’m looking to do is for a query to have these specific patterns already in the syntax so when the query is run there’s an extra column specifying the Stage dependent upon the t, n and m numbers that are in the table for each record.
So as above if t is t1, n is n2 and m is 0 there would be an extra column titled Stage with stage 3a for that record and so on for the variations. (See image for combinations).
I just can’t seem to figure out how to create that extra ‘Stage’ column and populate with the answer when the query is run.
I’m probably missing something very obvious. As I say it’s my first project with mySQL. I’m used to MSAccess I keep thinking a lot of the automation will still be there.
I HAVE to keep the separate T,N and M scores for each record within the schema for potential interrogation later.
I’ve looked at DERIVED, UNION, WHERE and HAVING and I just don’t know if I’m on the right track.
  CREATE TABLE pathology (
  pathology_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  medical_data_id VARCHAR(100),
  grade INT 
    CONSTRAINT grade CHECK (grade IN (1, 2, 3, 4)),
  tumour_weight DECIMAL (3,3)                       -- in grams
  tumour_circumference DECIMAL (2,2)                -- in cms
  tumour_stage ENUM('t0','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'),
  node_stage ENUM('n0', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3'),
  met_stage ENUM('m0', 'm1')
  );


There are 40 different combinations.  Do all 40 have a stage?  You could certain create a second table that has all 40 possible combinations and the resulting stage identifier, and do a LEFT JOIN to bring that into your query.

@TimRoberts Since the second table has all possible combinations, there's no reason to use LEFT JOIN, it should be INNER JOIN.

'So t1,n2,m0 is Stage3a' - WHY? how is 3a derived from this combination?

@P.Salmon it’s the way cancer stages are sorted. There is no mathematical reasoning. Just accumulating different scores depending on pathology results. So if m is 1 it will always be stage 4 because 1 means it’s metastasised.

@TimRoberts I have to keep the separate t,n,m scores per record saved within the schema for potential interrogation later.

@P.Salmon this table it used https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Stage-Groupings-Based-on-the-TNM-classification-of-the-Breast-Cancer_tbl1_287595146

@DonnaCannon You do NOT need the scores stored in the record.  In fact, that's considered poor practice, because it is redundant.  It's not Normal Form.  Wherever you would query the record, you just use the JOIN.  In fact, MySQL lets you do a CREATE VIEW that LOOKS like a table but does the JOIN for you, leaving the database structure intact.

If you have a table similar to this:
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table your_table ( id Int, T_stage Text, N_stage Text, M_stage Text );
Insert Into your_table
  Select  1, 'T0', 'N0', 'M0' Union All 
  Select  2, 'T0', 'N1', 'M0' Union All 
  Select  3, 'T0', 'N2', 'M0' Union All   
  Select  4, 'T0', 'N2', 'M1' Union All 
  Select  5, 'T1', 'N0', 'M0' Union All 
  Select  6, 'T1', 'N1', 'M0' Union All 
  Select  7, 'T1', 'N2', 'M0' Union All 
  Select  8, 'T3', 'N1', 'M0' Union All 
  Select  9, 'T3', 'N1', 'M1' Union All 
  Select 10, 'T3', 'N3', 'M0' Union All 
  Select 11, 'T4', 'N2', 'M0' Union All 
  Select 12, 'T4', 'N3', 'M0'; 

... you can create a cte (or a table) that defines different combinations of T, N and M stages giving them overall stage (as in your link above). I commented out the last 3 rows because they are distinctive and will be processed by Case expression in the Main SQL code below ...
WITH
  stages ( overall_stage, T_category, N_category, M_category ) AS
    ( Select 'Stage 0',   'T0',    'N0',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 1',   'T1',    'N0',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2A',  'T0',    'N1',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2A',  'T1',    'N1',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2A',  'T2',    'N0',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2B',  'T2', '   N1',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2B',  'T3',    'N0',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  'T0',    'N2',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  'T1',    'N2',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  'T2',    'N2',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  'T3',    'N1',    'M0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  'T3',    'N2',    'M0' 
      -- Union All 
      -- Select 'Stage 3B',  'T4',    'Any N', 'M0' Union All 
      -- Select 'Stage 3C',  'Any T', 'N3',    'M0' Union All 
      -- Select 'Stage 4',   'Any T', 'Any N', 'M1'   
    )

... this cte, when left joined to your_table, should give you the expected overall_stage for every row leaving your individual stages intact ...
--    M a i n    S Q L : 
Select      t.id, t.T_stage, t.N_stage, t.M_stage, 
            Case When t.M_stage = 'M1' Then 'Stage 4' 
                 When t.N_stage = 'N3' And t.M_stage = 'M0' Then 'Stage 3C'
                 When t.T_stage = 'T4' And t.M_stage = 'M0' Then 'Stage 3B'
                 When s.overall_stage Is Not Null Then s.overall_stage
            Else 'N/A'
            End as overall_stage
From        your_table t
Left Join   stages s ON( s.T_category = t.T_stage And 
                         s.N_category = t.N_stage And 
                         s.M_category = t.M_stage )
Order By    t.id

/*      R e s u l t :
id  T_stage     N_stage     M_stage     overall_stage
--  ---------   ----------  ----------  -------------
 1  T0          N0          M0          Stage 0
 2  T0          N1          M0          Stage 2A
 3  T0          N2          M0          Stage 3A
 4  T0          N2          M1          Stage 4
 5  T1          N0          M0          Stage 1
 6  T1          N1          M0          Stage 2A
 7  T1          N2          M0          Stage 3A
 8  T3          N1          M0          Stage 3A
 9  T3          N1          M1          Stage 4
10  T3          N3          M0          Stage 3C
11  T4          N2          M0          Stage 3B  
12  T4          N3          M0          Stage 3C       */

See the fiddle here.
NOTE:
Case expression is sequential - that is - the first When condition satisfied will return it's Then value and exit Case. Only issue could be which overall_stage has to be selected if you have a combination of T4-N3-M0 is it Stage 3C or 3B - I put 3C if that is opposite just  switch those two rows within the Case expression....
P.S. The best solution would be to create a permanent table with all explicite combinations of the three stages with apropriate overall_stage for each. Then you would't need Case expression at all - just the join selecting overall_stage from that new table for every joined row in your_table.

I have created a separate table called tnm_staging.  it contains all the combinations from the reference image I have been using.  I created a foreign key to connect the pathology table (which contains the individual t,n,m scores) to the tnm_staging (combination table).  I used a query which a user has specified above but with no luck with populating the return column.   Perhaps I have used the wrong join type.

@DonnaCannon refference image does not have all the explicite combinations of the three. There are things like ANY T or Tis which are not existing in the data (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4) . Try first to adjust the above code to your context (table name (your_table) and column names starting with t. in Main SQL above). Depending on your db's case sensitivity and actual data - it could work as is. If your db is case sensitive and you have 't0' instead of 'T0' then handle that too using Upper() or Lower() function in join's ON clause and in Case WHEN conditions...

I have created every permutation excluding Tis. That is so minor it would not occur in what this database, in theory, would be used for. I have ensured the cases are the same. I’d attach the code but this comment box won’t fit it in. Perhaps I’ll upload it remotely and send a link. If you have a link to fiddle maybe I could do it that way?

@DonnaCannon See the fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/PCC6tT_e I've generated all the combinations using recursive cte's (there are 40 combos). Below that combinations are sample data and working main sql code fetching the overall_stages.... (Used Oracle cause of multiple recursions and cause I'm used to Oracle)

You should have the table every possible combination written in your DB. Then, you can join the cases table with the matching rows in the combinations table, using fields T, N and M, which should give you the result you are looking for.
If your cases table name was X and you combinations table was Y, the predicate in you SQL should read somthing similar to this:
SELECT (...), Y.STAGE 
FROM X, Y
WHERE X.T=Y.T AND X.N=Y.N AND X.M=Y.M

According to the table you posted, there are some cases which allow any T or any N. For such cases, you should create some additional OR groups. Let me know if you need more elaboration on this.

I have now added the table code to my original question.  I'm not sure if I made it clear originally but the separate t, n, and m data has to be saved for each record for potential separate interrogation another time. So would the table with all combinations still work?

Yes, they would. With your table description now, consider T as tumour_stage, N as node_stage and M as met_stage. Your "pathology" (X) table will keep these values. You will need the additional "stages" (Y) table, which you will join with pathology with the criteria I explained above.

So I ran this query after creating and populating the combinations table (tnm_staging) and it gave me the column header but no data.  Sorry if I'm missing something very obvious.  I tried different combo where pathology_id is in this example. SELECT (pathology_id) overall_stage
FROM pathology, tnm_staging
WHERE pathology.tumour_stage=tnm_staging.t_category AND pathology.node_stage=tnm_staging.n_category AND pathology.met_stage=tnm_staging.n_category;

@DonnaCannon provided your tnm_staging table contains the right stage for every combination of t,n and m in the overall_stage field,, and your pathology table has at least one record with full data, this should work. The exact SQL query should be: SELECT pathology_id, tnm_staging.overall_stage FROM pathology, tnm_staging WHERE pathology.tumour_stage=tnm_staging.t_category AND pathology.node_stage=tnm_staging.n_category AND pathology.met_stage=tnm_staging.n_category; - Can you provide some sample data from your pathology table, just for checking?

SECOND ANSWER (after a lot of comments):
First create the tnm_staging table with all 40 possible explicite combination of the three column values defining the overall_stage column for each:
--  Combination generator for T 0-4   /    N 0-3    /    M 0-1
CREATE TABLE tnm_staging
WITH
  t_stages ( T_cat ) AS
    ( Select 't0' Union All
      Select 't1' Union All
      Select 't2' Union All
      Select 't3' Union All
      Select 't4'
    ), 
  n_stages (  N_cat ) AS
    ( Select 'n0' Union All
      Select 'n1' Union All
      Select 'n2' Union All
      Select 'n3' 
    ), 
  m_stages ( M_cat )  AS
    ( Select 'm0' Union All
      Select 'm1' 
    ),
  stages as
    ( Select Row_Number() Over(Order By tn.T_cat, tn.N_cat, m.M_cat) as id, 
             'Stage x' as overall_stage, tn.T_cat, tn.N_cat, m.M_cat
      From   ( Select  t.T_cat, n.N_cat 
               From    t_stages t
               CROSS JOIN n_stages n
             ) tn
      CROSS JOIN m_stages m
   ), 
  stage_names ( overall_stage, T_category, N_category, M_category ) AS
    ( Select 'Stage 0',   't0',    'n0',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 1',   't1',    'n0',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2A',  't0',    'n1',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2A',  't1',    'n1',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2A',  't2',    'n0',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2B',  't2',    'n1',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 2B',  't3',    'n0',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  't0',    'n2',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  't1',    'n2',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  't2',    'n2',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  't3',    'n1',    'm0' Union All 
      Select 'Stage 3A',  't3',    'n2',    'm0'    
    )
Select      t.id, t.T_cat as tumour_stage, t.N_cat as node_stage, t.M_cat as met_stage, 
            Case When t.M_cat = 'm1' Then 'Stage 4' 
                 When t.N_cat = 'n3' And t.M_cat = 'm0' Then 'Stage 3C'
                 When t.T_cat = 't4' And t.M_cat = 'm0' Then 'Stage 3B'
                 When s.overall_stage Is Not Null Then s.overall_stage
            Else 'N/A'
            End as overall_stage
From        stages t
Left Join   stage_names s ON( s.T_category = t.T_cat And 
                              s.N_category = t.N_cat And 
                              s.M_category = t.M_cat )
Order By    t.id;
SELECT * FROM tnm_staging;  -- this should resut with  40 different combinations each with it's own overall_stage following your rules

... and with your pathology table and data as :
CREATE TABLE pathology ( pathology_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,              
                           tumour_stage ENUM('t0','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'),
                           node_stage ENUM('n0', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3'),
                           met_stage ENUM('m0', 'm1')
                         );
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
pathology_id    tumour_stage    node_stage  met_stage
------------    ------------    ----------  ---------
01              t0              n0          m0
02              t0              n1          m0
03              t0              n2          m0
04              t0              n2          m1
05              t1              n0          m0
06              t1              n1          m0
07              t1              n2          m0
08              t3              n1          m0
09              t3              n1          m1
10              t3              n3          m0
11              t4              n2          m0
12              t4              n3          m0
13              t2              n1          m0

... join your pathology and tnm_staging tables to get the overal_stage column for every row in pathology table:
--      S Q L : 
Select      t.pathology_id, t.tumour_stage, t.node_stage, t.met_stage, 
            s.overall_stage
From        pathology t
Left Join   tnm_staging s ON( s.tumour_stage = t.tumour_stage And 
                              s.node_stage = t.node_stage And 
                              s.met_stage = t.met_stage )
Order By    t.pathology_id

See the fiddle here (with the results).

Fantastic thank you so much.  I can learn from reverse engineering this also now.  I've just added the extra fields and data in to the pathology table along with the tnm data I already had.  Thank you so much for your help and for sticking with a newbie to this site as well as MySQL.
